# How to change Firefox image background color back to white?

Tags: firefox, colors

I have problems viewing any transparent images, which have no background color set: the black lines are almost invisible on the dark gray background that Firefox has now set instead of the white color which was in use for 30 years(?).

Everyone has assumed the color is white for so long time, so all the transparent images are now hard to read.

How do i change the Firefox default background color for images (#222222) back to #FFFFFF ?

Firefox version: 13.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Old Default Image Style add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/old-default-image-style) to restore the old behaviour. It also allows you specify the exact background colour used, and keep the new centred alignment instead of the old top-left corner, if you want.